# How do I highlight certain words in a text, produced from a code chunkt?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have text blocks that are stored in a table, I want to Output them as a markdown pdf and highlight certain words in it. Stuff like "Data" or "Science".

I found that I can use
`\textcolor{red}{red}`
to produce a red text in the document. However, this does not work, when code chunks provide the Basis for the text. How do I do this?

---

title: "Example"
author: ""
date: "20 5 2019"

### output: pdf_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

this works : Roses are \textcolor{red}{red}

```
mytext <- "I have a very important message"

mytext2 <- str_replace_all(mytext,"have","\textcolor{have}{red}")
mytext3 <- str_replace_all(mytext,"have","\\textcolor{have}{red}")
```

`r mytext2`
`r mytext3`

only produces:

```
I extcolor{have}{red} a very important message I textcolor{have}{red} a very important message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gsub("have","\\\\textcolor{red}{have}", mytext)
```

It makes no difference if you use `gsub` or `str_replace_all`. The important change is to use 4 backslashes. And you have to change the argument order for `textcolor`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Could you clarify /link a ressource About how I determine the number of escape \ I have to use instead of  a trial and error Approach?

Comment: That is due to the process. First the RMD gets converted to MD and then to tex using pandoc. In the first step the backslash has to be escaped and for the second conversion as well. So we go from 4 slashes, to 2 and resulting in 1 slash in the tex file. That is my understanding.